# listing of neutral cultures

Tags: c++, winapi, globalization

How do I list neutral cultures in C++/WinAPI application? For specific cultures EnumSystemLocales function works reasonably well, but for some reason it does not list neutral cultures. In the end I want to have LCID<=>culture name mapping (eg. 1045<=>pl-PL and 21<=>pl).

Comment: Can you use EnumSystemLocalesEx? What OS do you need to support? (XP? Vista? Win7? Server? Client?)

Comment: Windows XP at minimum (though the code currently can run on Windows 2000). In that situation I guess the only solution would be to hard code the table in the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you want to do is to map between LCIDs and locale names, then [LCIDToLocaleName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318698%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with LOCALE_ALLOW_NEUTRAL_NAMES flag (Win 7 and above) and [LocaleNameToLCID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318711%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) also with LOCALE_ALLOW_NEUTRAL_NAMES flag (Win 7 and above) is probably what you want. [EnumSystemLocalesEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd317829%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with LOCALE_NEUTRALDATA flag (Win 7 and above) will list the neutral cultures.

Comment: For XP you're stuck with carrying your own data. This data isn't exposed.